# Mysql, how to select based on result set from another query in one shot

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, mariadb

I have two tables, first let's called it brand_table, structured like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>brand_id</th>
    <th>brand_name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Honda</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Ford</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

the other is, user_table, structured like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>user_id</th>
    <th>username</th>
    <th>favorite_brands</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>John Wick</td>
    <td>1,2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Jack Reaper</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Han Solo</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Presumably, I can know how much users who likes a particular brand by:

```
select  count(*)
    from  table_user
    where  favorite_brands like 
    (
        SELECT  concat('%', brand_id, '%')
            from  brand_table
            where  brand_id = <brand_id>
    )
```

Now, if I want to know the total users who likes each of the brands, then I would have to do it in two phases and even do it in the programming side:

- First, load all the brands and stores them in a result set
- Second, iterate into the result set and find out the total users for each brand_id

What I wanted to do is execute this in a single query.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Why does the table have a single record for `user_id 1` with `favourite_brands` as `1,2` instead of 2 records for `user_id 1`, one for each brand that user likes as favourite?

Comment: Tip: Use `FIND_IN_SET()` instead of `LIKE` .

Comment: Since you have `<brand_id>`, don't use a `SELECT`!  Anyway, guest what happens when you end up with `"3,12" LIKE '%1%'` -- Wrong result.

Comment: thanks @RickJames, really thoughtful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the two tables based on a given brand being present in a given user's list of brands.  Towards this end, we can use `FIND_IN_SET` which can search a CSV list of values for a given input.  As an example of how `FIND_IN_SET` works, `FIND_IN_SET('1', '1,2,3')` would return the index 1 since `1` occurs as the first value in the CSV list.  `FIND_IN_SET` returns zero for no match, so as long as a non zero value is returned we can assume that the CSV contains our value of interest.

```
SELECT
    t1.brand_id,
    t1.brand_name,
    COUNT(t2.favorite_brands) AS cnt
FROM brand_table t1
LEFT JOIN user_table t2
    ON FIND_IN_SET(t1.brand_id, t2.favorite_brands) > 0
GROUP BY
    t1.brand_id,
    t1.brand_name
```

**Output:**

```
    brand_id    brand_name  cnt
1   1           Honda       2
2   2           Ford        2
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Nice answer Tim Biegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
select count(*) from user_table where FIND_IN_SET(<brand_id>,favorite_brands);
```